# Load post content into iframe

Tags: php, customization, iframe

I would like to load a WordPress post into an `iframe` when a link on a WordPress page is clicked. This is the link I currently have.

```
<a href="' . get_post_permalink($sight->ID) . '" target="map-loader">Read the report</a>
```

Then I want the content of that post (no header or footer etc) to load into an iframe when the link is clicked. This is the iframe that is on the page.

```
<iframe name="map-loader" src="map-iframe.php"></iframe>
```

I am half way there. When the link is clicked, the iframe loads a full wordpress page with the header and footer etc. what I want is the actual post content to be loaded into the iframe, no header or footer.

I have tried this in map-iframe.php but no success. Still loads the whole wordpress template.

```
<?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
```

I'm thinking that my link needs something that specifies that I only want to load the post content.

Or would it be better to load with ajax?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, but I think ajax solution would be more apropriate.

But anyways, if I understand this corectly, you have an archive where full posts are loaded inside iframe.

If this is a case you can modify template file (single.php) and remove header and footer

take a look at [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

for further reading I found this which will guide you to more advanced features:http://bavotasan.com/2009/custom-template-for-single-posts-in-wordpress/

**Note**: if you also want to get rid of adminbar, try this: `show_admin_bar(false);` at the top of your code.

Have not tested but if this does not work, you can hook inside `init`
and check

```
if(is_page()) {
    show_admin_bar(false);
}
```

---

Edit:

You can also setup a new page which will get post depending on ID.

First lets create custom-template

- In your themes folder create file template-iframe.php (for example)
- put this code inside

---

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: IFrame
*/
   $id = intval($_GET["ID"]);
   $post = get_post($id);
   var_dump($post);
?>
```

- Then go to dashboard and create page iframe and in the sidebar where it says: template, choose now created template (Iframe)
- save and go to url and time http://yoururl.domain/iframe/?ID=1

it should give you back your post

Of course you need to design your own template.

Comment: Thanks but not sure if that is what I want. Adjusting single.php will change all my posts. I have a page that contains links to some posts. When those links are clicked, I want to load the content of the post in either an iframe or a div with ajax. Think of it as loading a little preview of the post content in a light box. Meanwhile all other posts still need the full template when they are viewed under normal circumstances on other parts of the site.

Comment: see edited version, write back if you need more info